# Update Version Number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which holds accounts inside them. The accounts are supposed to be unique meaning there should only be one version active of the account. However, there are multiple versions active. The problem I am having is that the version number equals 1 for each instance. This should not happen The versioning should be based on the AccountFileDate. What I would like to see is say that I have 4 of the same accounts, I would like to see the oldest AccountFileDate get version 1, then the next 2, then 3 and so on. All of them are one right now though and I would like to update these either by grouping and using row_number or grouping and using the unique identity column ScheduleRowId. How can I made this work please show some code

Comment: It is not understandable. Try to include a data sample, rewrite the question and what's more, show what did you do by now.

Comment: Look at CTEs and the ROW_NUMBER() function. What you want to do is certainly doable with those two things. 1) Create a CTE with ROW_NUMBER to number the rows for each account, partitioned by account, ordered by date, and then do an update from that CTE to set the version equal to the row number. If you posted example schema and data, we could give you SQL that will do it, but you should be able to figure it out yourself from these hints.

Comment: I would be happy to share some code, as soon as you share the table structure (create table statements), sample data (insert statements) and the desired output for the sample data. Without those details how can you expect somebody to write any code? [mcve]